# How are static aspx pages served compared to dynamic aspx pages?

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t

First off I'm using Tridion 9.5 with DD4T 2.5 (should this matter)

I'm wondering how aspx pages are served when they have been published statically vs dynamically.

We have a .NET website that serves the webpages. When you perform a call to an aspx page I would expect the corresponding controller to be called.

While debugging the website I've noticed that when requesting a page that has been published statically the controller is not triggered. Does the Tridion Content Delivery intercept these calls and serves the webpage instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DD4T is a framework which retrieves pages from the CD database. Pages are published as JSON into that database, with the help of the DD4T templates. You don't publish pages as ASPX at all. If you do, however, it is likely that they will be served by your .NET web application because if IIS finds a static file matching the request, it will normally serve that directly, without going to the MVC context at all.

I suggest you read a bit more about DD4T. Useful reading: https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/wiki or http://blog.trivident.com/dd4t-page-and-content-viewmodels/.